# How can I modify an angular ng-model from my C# code behind file?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, angularjs, episerver

The problem is, if I add the directive ng-model to any of my asp:TextBox's, then I cannot change their value from my code behind file. The ng-model is tied to vm.Company, which I cannot access from my code behind. I would do this all in javascript, but I do not know how to get EPiServerProfile.current outside of .NET.

User Control (.ascx) :

```
<div class="container" data-ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-controller="membershipsettingscontrol as vm" class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <label for="txtCompanyName">Company Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyName" data-ng-model="vm.Company" data-ng-disabled="false" />
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

My Code behind file (.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                currentProfile = EPiServerProfile.Current;
                txtCompanyName.Text = currentProfile.Company;
            }
        }
```

app.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'membershipsettingscontrol';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$location', 'datacontext.sbcountry', 'datacontext.sbstates', 'datacontext.sbcontact', admin]);

    function admin($scope, $location, sbcountrydatacontext, sbstatesdatacontext, sbcontactdatacontext) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Job Add';

        vm.states = [];
        vm.Address = {};

        vm.getStates = getStates;
        vm.submit = submit;

        getCountries();
        pageLoad();

        function getCountries() {
            return sbcountrydatacontext.getCountries().then(function (httpResults) {
                vm.countries = httpResults.data.Countries;
            });
        }

        function getStates(country) {
            return sbstatesdatacontext.getStates(country).then(function (httpResults) {
                vm.states = httpResults.data.States;
            });
        }

        function submit(data) {
            return sbcontactdatacontext.updateContact(data);
        }


    }
})();
```

Comment: It looks like you're not using angular the way it was intended.  By testing postback, you've reverted to a webforms style instead of the ajax centric MVC.

Comment: So what route do you suggest for this then? Getting the current profile of the user logged in (EPiServerProfile.Current) is forcing me to use the code behind.

Comment: You should expose an endpoint for angular to consume. You should look at WebAPI for this. Then you can just use the `$http` service in angular to pull a JSON object back with the users profile details and update your model in your angular controller.